# add ascii qr code to alpine signature file

Tags: qr-code, alpine-linux

I'm trying to add an ASCII qr code to the signatura file (~/.signature).
The code is generated via `qrencode`, and in alpine it looks like this:

[image]

But after sending the email, for instance, in gmail it looks like this:

[image]

The signature file can be found here: [signature file](https://yadi.sk/d/oq0FL32tbuugzA)

Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: Are you sending it as an attachment or in the body of the email? I just sent it as an attachment through gmail and received the file exactly as is. My test was fairly simple, though, so it could be a false positive.

Comment: @phentnil I'm using signature feature in alpine, I think it just concatenare it to the rest of the email. So it is in the body...

Comment: Ah, I understand. Have you referenced the [signature](https://alpine.x10host.com/alpine/alpine-info/misc/signature.html) documentation? It has information about creating the file and setting up configurations, but not much on ensuring contents remain in the format you're expecting.

Comment: yeah, I also checked it out...

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

##############      ##  ##    ##########    ##############
##          ##  ####    ####  ##    ##  ##  ##          ##
##  ######  ##  ##    ####  ########  ##    ##  ######  ##
##  ######  ##    ##  ####    ##    ####    ##  ######  ##
##  ######  ##  ####    ######  ######      ##  ######  ##
##          ##  ##  ##  ####  ####  ######  ##          ##
##############  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##############
                ##  ##  ##  ####  ########                
####  ##    ####  ####      ##  ##  ####    ######  ####  
  ##  ######      ####    ##              ####    ##    ##
######  ######  ##          ##  ####  ########    ######  
####  ##          ##      ####  ##  ##    ##  ####  ####  
####      ####      ####  ####  ####  ########    ##  ####
  ##      ##  ##    ##      ##        ######  ##          
      ##  ########  ########      ####  ##        ########
        ####    ####  ##  ##############          ##  ##  
    ##  ##  ####        ##    ##  ##    ####  ##      ##  
  ##  ##  ##  ##      ##    ##    ##      ######  ##    ##
##          ##  ##  ##  ##        ##    ####  ##      ####
      ######    ####        ##  ####    ####          ####
##  ##    ####        ########      ##  ##########  ##    
                ####    ####    ##    ####      ##  ######
##############  ##  ##  ####    ####    ##  ##  ##    ##  
##          ##    ######  ##  ##    ##  ##      ##########
##  ######  ##      ##  ####  ######    ##########    ##  
##  ######  ##  ####    ######        ##    ##  ########  
##  ######  ##        ##  ##      ##  ##        ######  ##
##          ##  ##    ######  ######  ########  ##    ##  
##############  ##  ######  ##  ####    ##########

Instead of:

```
##############      ##  ##    ##########    ##############
##          ##  ####    ####  ##    ##  ##  ##          ##
##  ######  ##  ##    ####  ########  ##    ##  ######  ##
##  ######  ##    ##  ####    ##    ####    ##  ######  ##
##  ######  ##  ####    ######  ######      ##  ######  ##
##          ##  ##  ##  ####  ####  ######  ##          ##
##############  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##  ##############
                ##  ##  ##  ####  ########                
####  ##    ####  ####      ##  ##  ####    ######  ####  
  ##  ######      ####    ##              ####    ##    ##
######  ######  ##          ##  ####  ########    ######  
####  ##          ##      ####  ##  ##    ##  ####  ####  
####      ####      ####  ####  ####  ########    ##  ####
  ##      ##  ##    ##      ##        ######  ##          
      ##  ########  ########      ####  ##        ########
        ####    ####  ##  ##############          ##  ##  
    ##  ##  ####        ##    ##  ##    ####  ##      ##  
  ##  ##  ##  ##      ##    ##    ##      ######  ##    ##
##          ##  ##  ##  ##        ##    ####  ##      ####
      ######    ####        ##  ####    ####          ####
##  ##    ####        ########      ##  ##########  ##    
                ####    ####    ##    ####      ##  ######
##############  ##  ##  ####    ####    ##  ##  ##    ##  
##          ##    ######  ##  ##    ##  ##      ##########
##  ######  ##      ##  ####  ######    ##########    ##  
##  ######  ##  ####    ######        ##    ##  ########  
##  ######  ##        ##  ##      ##  ##        ######  ##
##          ##  ##    ######  ######  ########  ##    ##  
##############  ##  ######  ##  ####    ##########
```

The difference is that the regular space character used in the second qrcode was replaced with the unicode U+2007 &#8199 in the first one, which is a different space character that happens to use the same space as `#`. As you can see it wasn't necessary even to blockquote them, their space was fixed by itself.

The problem here is that alpine sends text only emails (mime type `text/plain`) and gmail instead of showing it in a monospaced font, it shows it in `Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif`. If you open the "bad" email in any cli email client like Alpine it will be shown as "good", because cli are forced to use monoscpaced fonts by nature. Gmail has decided helvetica font family is better than monospaced, trading off this ability to handle better those "ascii art" emails.

Trying to force Alpine to send `text/html` emails by embedding HTML tags or trying to insert `Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"` in the message didn't work.

With this limitation, we still can take advantage of the great variety of symbols that unicode has to offer and choose a combination of black and white characters that solves this problem of having the same spacing for this font family `Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif`. By keeping your `#` as the black character in the QR Code and using U+2007 &#8199 Figure Space your problem is solved.

If you want to try other black characters like this one █ to make your QR-code more solid, you can try, but then you need to find a equally-spaced space character, and also test if the vertical proportions are ok. It is also good to check for different environments - windows with x fonts installed, mac with y fonts installed and linux with z fonts installed may have different opnions about the fonts `Arial`, `Helvetica` and `sans-serif` and their respective spacings.

Comment: cool!, so how do I replace the regular space easily enough in any qr code generated by `qrencode`?

Comment: right after running qrencode you pipe it to a sed and replace it: `qrencode -t ascii 1234567890 | sed "s/ / /g"` (if you were using `qrencode ... -o filename`, you would use `qr encode ... | sed ... > filename` instead

Comment: it works in maintaining the width, but the code isn't easily recognized as before... what would be the equivalent if I use UTF8 instead of ASCII in qrcode?

Comment: it is not easily recognized as before probably because arial's version of `#` is less heavy than the monospaced original. and `qrencode -t UTF8` is really way more appealing, but when rendered as `Arial/Heveltica` they got misaligned with all 16 different unicode white spaces that I had.

Comment: I spent some time looking for different heavy chars (■,◾,▮,◼, █) and still didn't find one with an equivalent white-space width - hint: you don't need to send emails to test, your libreoffice writer is enough for initial tests (or maybe a browser)

Comment: i believe we need to automate, use some tool like this python `https://github.com/fonttools/fonttools/wiki/How-do-I...%3F`, to generate a list of spacing widths, and maybe PIL to stamp them in whitespace, sum the pixels, divide by area and have a list of spacing widths and boldnesses, then from the list of heaviest against the lightest per spacing width, choose the one that seems ideal (rembember that maybe they must respect also vertical ratios).

Answer (score 0):

By default, Gmail client limits the width of your text. You can adjust your email's inline styles to prevent text wrapping:

```
<table style="width: 100%; max-width: 600px; white-space: nowrap">
...
<table>
```

Comment: where do i put this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<pre>` which preformatted text which is to be presented exactly as written in the HTML file. You can learn more about at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre

Thanks.